# can't understand ".this" in mongoose virtual

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

```
userSchema.virtual("password")
      .set(function(password) {
          //temp var
          this._password = password;

          //gen salt
          this.salt = this.makeSalt();

          //encrypt pass
          this.hashed_password = this.encryptPassword(password);

      })
      .get(function () {
          return this._password;
      });
```

i want to know the scope the "this" is refering to in the above code.i got a mongo schema called userSchema for which i am setting up a virtual field i.e password.Just curious about what the this refers to here as normally inside a function call this refers to the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

This is referring to the target field.

On a side note if you are trying to encrypt the password I would go with “pre” instead of a virtual to store the encrypted password

Comment: Thanks mate.I am not storing the password as virtual rather the input from the user.